# Are there different versions of 4060 counter IC available?

Tags: datasheet, binary, ripple-counter

I was searching for datasheet of 4060 IC (my part number is HEF4060BT, made by NXP) and found different versions with different stages.
Is this just a vast typo in labeling pins in datasheets or some claimed 14-stage counter ICs are actually 13-stage as the pinouts suggest?

Some pics from different datasheets:
[image: ds1]
[image: ds2]
[image: ds3]
[image: ds nxp]

Comment: There *are* different versions of 4060, but they all have the same pinout and number of stages. The differences are in the power consumption and speed, mostly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you start counting at 0 or at 1? That's the difference. They all use a 14 stage ripple counter and, the first-stage output is called Q0 by some folk and Q1 by others.

[image]

And, because this device also uses a 14-stage ripple counter: -

[image]

Comment: So any 4060 chip is able to divide by 16384 at its pin 3?

Comment: Correct, they have a 14-stage divider @Bikay